# "deplete" vs "dwindle"

Tags: difference

Could someone please tell me if *Deplete* and *Dwindle* are completely interchangeable in the text below?

> Anlong Veng is mostly populated by former Khmer Rouge cadres and their
> progeny. The fanatical regime's surviving leaders, **depleted** militia and
> **dwindling** supporters decamped there in the 1980s after Vietnam toppled
> the Khmer Rouge and installed a new government.
>
> <sub>Source : [Time Magazine](http://content.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,2010217,00.html) (The online version doesn't contain this paragraph. It's somewhat longer than the paper version.)</sub>

Comment: I won't say it's General Reference, but in fact the cited usage pretty much captures the difference in usage. If they *were* completely interchangeable, the writer could more succinctly have used *depleted militia and supporters* or *dwindling militia and supporters*. The reason he didn't is precisely *because of* the (slight) differences outlined by @user3169.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> depleted militia

is talking about a militia that has used up all its resources. This could be manpower (such as soldiers) or equipment (such as tanks, guns etc.). Also the militia effectiveness has been reduced.

> dwindling supporters

is referring to a reduced quantity of supporters.

So **deplete** has more to do with used up resources or effect, while **dwindle** has more to do with quantity reduction. If you check the definitions I think you can see the difference.

Comment: Thank you :) **Deplete**  and **Dwindle** seemed very alike to me.I thought maybe the writer had tried to avoid repeating the same word.

Comment: @GATA: Per my comment to the question, your thinking is the exact opposite of what's really going on.